# change values of a nested dictionary dynamically in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary in nested dictionary python which i want to update dynamically.

My dictionary format

```
sample_control = {
    77000: {
        (5,100034): 1,   
        (5,100043): 1,                         
        (2,100014): 50.,  # target value
        (2,100020): 50.,  
        (2,100073): 0.,  
    }
}
```

target value is calculated dynamically and i want to update the target value in the dictionary.

code -

```
def calculateTarget():
     #some calculations 
     #target is calculated
```

how to update my dictionary every time a new target is calculated

Thanks

Comment: How does it get updated? I mean in which way, do you need to add data, replace data or delete data?

Comment: Hi @Wimanicesir, once the target variable is calculated, as shown in my dictionary format, the update dictionary should be with new value of target variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in general you can update a dictionary with any function / expression that returns a value

for example if you wanted to multiply the key of the top level dictionary with the first item in the tuple key of the nested dict you could do something like this:

```
sample_control = {
                77000: {
                            (5,100034): 1,   
                            (5,100043): 1,                         
                            (2,100014): 50.,  # target value
                            (2,100020): 50.,  
                            (2,100073): 0.,  
                        }
            }

def calculateTarget(a, b):
    return a * b

for key, nested_dict in sample_control.items():
    for nested_key in nested_dict:
        nested_dict[nested_key] = calculateTarget(key, nested_key[0])
```

which gives:

```
{77000: {(5, 100034): 385000,
  (5, 100043): 385000,
  (2, 100014): 154000,
  (2, 100020): 154000,
  (2, 100073): 154000}}
```

which you.... might want?